# Facebook private messages delivery

Tags: facebook

Is it possible that Facebook actually doesn't deliver your private message to a friend? As in, it's in your sent messages, and you see it as sent in the message thread with that friend, but the friend claims that they never received it, and shows you the same message thread from their Facebook account without that message in it? Basically, does that mean that the friend either deliberately (which is more likely) or accidentally deleted your message, or is it actually possible that Facebook made a mistake and didn't really deliver the message in question to your friend?

I'd especially like to know if it's possible for a mistake like that to happen more than once in a short period of time.

Comment: I can say for sure that it happens (it happened to me at list) with the delivery of the message to the email account attached to your Facebook account— **not** the Facebook email address (`@facebook`), but the email address of your user (e.g. `@yahoo` or `@gmail` or whatever).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Alex. That's happened to me as well, with gmail. But my question specifically relates to your Facebook inbox, on your Facebook account - is it possible that a message someone sent you on Facebook is not delivered to your Facebook inbox, by some Facebook mistake? That you just do not receive at all a private message that someone did definitely send you? Does Facebook make such mistakes?

Comment: I understood your question, but I don’t know the answer—I haven’t noticed the behavior you described—, so I can only speculate. Could this happen? Yes, I believe it could. Does it happen? I don’t know. But I did noticed the behavior I described above, so that’s why I say that it _could_ happen (again, this is pure speculation).

Comment: Thanks again. Those were pretty much my thoughts, too. Maybe someone else will have a more precise and certain idea and let us know.